# Python multiprocessing.Queue.get raises EOFError on first call

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using python 3.7 on ubuntu 20.04 OS. My problem statement is similar to that of producer and consumer problem, where there is a pair of reader and writer processes. My reader process calls Queue.get in an infinite loop, (As per documentation, the Queue.get is blocking call until any data is put into the queue by another process).

Making this call raises EOFError.

reader.py

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def reader(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            data = queue.get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception occurred: {e}')
        # Do something

queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=reader, args=(queue,))
p.start()
# Prepare some data to send
queue.put(some_data)
# Do my own tasks
```

Running This results in

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/src/processor.py", line 775, in classification_manager
    slot_data = classification_queue.get()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 819, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
2022-02-18 20:45:01,528 classification_1 INFO     Waiting for Data!
2022-02-18 20:45:01,528 classification_1 ERROR    BrokenPipeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/src/processor.py", line 775, in classification_manager
    slot_data = classification_queue.get()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 818, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 404, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: The code you show is from `reader.py`, yet the error message you show are from `processor.py`.  Are you saying your code sample generates a similar error?

Comment: Why I run your sample code I get completely different error.

Comment: Please post a working demonstration... the details matter. You'll get that error if the parent process exits while the child is still using the queue. Do you see some data processing before this error?

Comment: The parent exiting without terminating the child explains the EOFError, but not the following broken pipe error. Are you catching the EOFError and trying again?

Comment: @RufusVS the reader.py is just a demonstration that I can upload. I can't just upload the actual codebase of my repositiory as of now.

Comment: @tdelaney In my case, the parent process never exits. It's a forever running process (Just like a server). I'm catching any exception that occurs in the child process. So, for the first time I'm getting EOFError and then in every iteration I'm getting BrokenPipeError.

Comment: @BhaveshAchhada  When you provide example code, you should run the example code and post the error from the example,  so the code and error are correlated (plus doing that might have clarified the issue in your own mind.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. In my case, the Linux OOM killer was killing the parent process. That's why the child process was getting this EOFError and then BrokenPipeError.

You can read about linux OOM killer [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html).

Answer (score 0):

The threading equivalent to your code works fine:

```
import threading as th
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep

def reader(queue):
    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        print ("Reader saw",data)
        # Do something

queue = Queue()
p = th.Thread(target=reader, args=(queue,))
p.start()

queue.put("Expect More Data")

call_count = 0
while True:
    sleep(2)
    call_count += 1
    queue.put(call_count)
```

Comment: I just cannot use multi-threaded model in my application, I've some computation intensive tasks, which I have divided into several processes.

Answer (score 0):

If I just elaborate your code (which isn't runnable as it stands) then there's no problem at all.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def reader(queue):
    while (data := queue.get()) != 'stop':
        print(data)

def main():
    queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=reader, args=(queue,))
    p.start()
    for some_data in ['Hello', 'world', 'stop']:
        queue.put(some_data)
    p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
world
```

Comment: Except that's the problem, isn't it? OP doesn't have a way to exit the child process and doesn't join the subprocess in the parent. Those are the bugs. I'd say your additions are the answer.

Comment: @tdelaney If OP's process runs indefinitely then join() is irrelevant. Of course, having no (clean) way to terminate the process is bad practice IMO. Having said that, the issue is allegedly occurring during get() on the queue. What I've tried to show is that queue handling is simple and robust. OP's code (as shown) doesn't seem to have anything to do with his/her real problem

Comment: Actually I found the problem. The parent process was killed abnormally. That's why the child process was getting the EOFError and BrokenPipeError.